# Fedora14 serial console how-to needed

Tags: linux, console, upstart, serial

Has anyone ever got a serial console working in fedora 14 ?

Is it as simple as adding to grub:

```
serial --unit=0 --speed=38400

terminal --timeout=10 serial console
```

and add to the kernel lines: `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400`

If so, this isn't working for me. I have agetty installed, and I'm using minicom. The `/etc/init/serial.conf` file suggests it should pick up the kernel lines and begin working, but i get just nothing.

Currently getting no joy from any of this after 2 days. Does anyone know a method that definitely works on fedora 14 ? (no `/etc/event.d/` needed or such)

Client side I'm using a null modem cable and usb-serial adaptor.

Comment: even when i manually run /sbin/agetty -L -i 38400 ttyS0 vt102, still nothing

Comment: Im having similar problems however `/sbin/agetty -L 9600 ttyS0 vt102` works for me i removed the `-i` and changed `38400` to `9600` and the last `vt102` to `vt100`....... However when i put it into inittab this line `s0:123456:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L 9600 ttyS0 vt100` i get nothing :(

Comment: Run the command `ps aux |grep tty`. If the Kernel, `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and `/etc/init/serial.conf` are configured correctly, then you will see a line like `/sbin/agetty /dev/ttyS0 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the grub load and serial but i managed to get the getty or the login part working through serial on fedora 13

Create a file in `/etc/init` called `serial-ttySx.conf` Where `x` is the serial port Number

and in this file add this

```
#This service maintains a getty on /dev/ttyS0.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on starting runlevel [016]

respawn
exec /sbin/agetty /dev/ttyS0 9600 vt100-nav
```

Comment: Normally, this shouldn't be needed if you have the appropriate `kernel... console=ttyX` setting in grub.conf. The Upstart file at `/etc/init/serial.conf` should do everything needed to automatically start the serial console for the primary console (the last console on the commandline in grub).

Answer (score 0):

The terminal line may cause issues, as it'll try pumping grub to the serial interface and grub in fedora 14 uses a splashimage. If the machine is headless you'll need that turned off anyhow to boot without the gfx card also.

Try disabling the terminal line, and try running minicom on both ends of the connection initially to check connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Added to grub:

```
timeout=0
serial --unit=3 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1 timeout=5
terminal --timeout=2 serial console
```

Added to kernel cmd line:

```
quiet console=tty0 console=ttyS3,115200n8
```

Removed from kernel cmd line:

```
rhgb
```

Comment: It can  be helpful to explain what you're doing in your answer.